# How to set statement timeout per user?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, users, postgresql-11, query-timeout

I have multiple users in Postgres. I would like to set up different statement timeouts for different users.
Eg: Guest 5 minutes and Admin 10 minutes.

Is it possible in Postgres 11.11?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Postgres allows settings per user or even per database and user, including [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT):

```
ALTER ROLE foo SET statement_timeout = 12345;  -- milliseconds
```

Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

To see the currently active setting for the session:

```
SHOW statement_timeout;
```

Or get more details from the view [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html) (including how it was set):

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name = 'statement_timeout';
```

To check current settings for a role:

```
SELECT rolname, rolconfig
FROM   pg_roles
WHERE  rolname = 'foo';
```

[`rolconfig`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html) is an array, unnest it to get one setting per row:

```
SELECT rolname, unnest(rolconfig) AS setting
FROM   pg_roles
WHERE  rolname = 'foo';
```

Comment: This does not prevent the user from changing the statement_timeout back though, which makes it kinda useless for anything security related

Comment: Is this also working for AWS RDS Postgresql?

Comment: @phiresky I think it does. superuser can set statement_timeout for other user. other user can change it, but it won't make effect. the statement_timeout will set as per superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Found that we can set the timeout on Role.

```
ALTER ROLE guest SET statement_timeout='5min';
ALTER ROLE admin SET statement_timeout='10min';
```

Comment: Use min or ms, because m was deprecated.

Comment: Tested: alter role xxx set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '90m';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout": "90m"
HINT:  Valid units for this parameter are "us", "ms", "s", "min", "h", and "d".